# GPIO output corrector

Tags: voltage, raspberry-pi, gpio

It was suggested to me that `GPIO` outputs on Raspberry cannot be used as a reference voltage: for example `GPIO` `TRUE` might give only 3.2V and `GPIO` `FALSE` could give 0.1V.  On the other hand, according to [Exploring the 3.3V Power Rail](https://raspberrypise.tumblr.com/post/144555785379/exploring-the-33v-power-rail) 3.3V rail should be rather stable .  What I want to do is to correct `GPIO` output in a way that it really returns something very close to rail voltage (3.3V) when `TRUE` and something really close to ground voltage (0.0V) when `FALSE`:

[image]

I would be satisfied also with the inverted logic solution, i.e. that it returns something very close to rail voltage (3.3V) when `FALSE` and something very close to ground voltage (0.0V) `TRUE`.  I know that *in principle* inverters should do such a job, but I don't know how precise they are.

I have several questions:

- What is the simplest circuit do the job?
- Would ready-made inverters be good enough for inverted logic solution?

Specification for the circuit:

- current output less than 1 mA,
- `TRUE`/`FALSE` or `FALSE`/`TRUE` voltages on `OUT` less than 0.04V from rail voltage and ground voltage.

I already assumed (hopefully I am right) that rail voltage is within few percents of 3.3V.

---

@Andy aka's solution:

[image]

Reference output voltage can be regulated between 0V and 1V.  For `GPIO`=`FALSE`, `OUT` equals reference voltage.  For `GPIO`=`TRUE`, `OUT` is (according to my calculations) less than 1 uV.

(Could you please confirm this is your proposed solution?)

Comment: "Does this circuit do the job?" rather depends what the job is. How stable do you need this output to be and how much load does it expect?

Comment: Hmm, what problems are you having to begin with? Why is the High signal from the GPIO not enough?

Comment: Your mosfets are wrongly placed. P channel should be at the top.

Comment: @Finbarr I need that the output is as close as and as stable as possible to 3.3V rail.  The output goes to voltage divider with at least few dozen kiloohms.

Comment: @WesleyLee I was told that GPIO is not reliable enough, that High signal could be, say, only 3V.

Comment: @Andyaka This is not inverter / NOT logic.  Quite opposite, I explained in the question.

Comment: The answer could be anything from using an N-FET with a pull-up to 3.3V, to actually measuring the output of your RPi (it could be 3.3V and enough), to maybe an Enable pin on a 3.3V reference. Or adjusting your resistive divider.

Comment: If that's an N-fet at the top, it won't actually turn on!

Comment: @pcj50 *facepalm* you are right.  My solution sucks.  I'll rephrase the question without my "solution".

Comment: If it absolutely has to be 3.3V, what I would do is have a *separate* LDO, with its own decoupling capacitors, driven from the 5V rail, with an enable input (EN or ~EN pin) driven from the GPIO.

Comment: @pjc50 Supposing that GPIO TRUE gives 3.2V and GPIO FALSE gives 0.1, I would need something that gives 3.3V or 0.0V for GPIO TRUE and 0.0V and 3.3V for GPIO FALSE.

Comment: But what do you actually need _exactly_ 3.3V from a GPIO for? Are you building a resistor DAC or something along those lines?

Comment: @Pygmalion no you are incorrect, it needs to be a P channel at the top.

Comment: @RichardtheSpacecat I need relatively precise reference voltage for current controller.  With GPIO ON voltage should be, say, 0.5V, for GPIO OFF volrage should be 0 V, which would stop current completely.  Negative logic is also OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a comment by the OP: -

> I need relatively precise reference voltage for current controller.
>   With GPIO ON voltage should be, say, 0.5V, for GPIO OFF volrage should
>   be 0 V, which would stop current completely. Negative logic is also
>   OK.

This implies to me you would use a resistor potential divider to create 0.5 volts from 3.3 volts so...

The simplest solution would be to hard-connect the top resistor to +3.3 volts and use an N channel MOSFET to clamp the reference input (previously 0.5 volts) to 0 volts.

Comment: A resistor devider is not precise, especially when VCC or load current changes.

Comment: @TurboJ It may still be good enough, depending on the job. Since we still don't have any precise specification of what the OP _really_ wants to achieve, any answer counts, I guess.

Comment: @RichardtheSpacecat I would expect that better precision means more complex circuit.  What I really want is the solution that any amateur (like me) is easily capable of building.  It is a great simplification if we *assume* that 3.3V line is stable enough (with, say, few percent error).  Of course if GPIO output is equally precise, then the question is pointless.

Comment: I know how to build voltage divider, however, it is to me very fuzzy, how to turn on/turn off voltage divider output when changing `GPIO` logic.

Comment: @Pygmalion the N channel MOSFET can be made to operate like an on/off switch. When off (open circuit), the reference input at your chip is 0.5 volts and, when the MOSFET is on, it acts like a short circuit and pulls you ref input down to 0 volts. Drain to ref input, source to 0 volts and gate to IO pin. Choose a MOSFET with low on resistance (say below 0.1 ohms). Also, what are you resistor values you talk about that set the 0.5 volts?

Comment: I think I got the idea.

Comment: @Andyaka I posted your suggestion as I undestood it as another answer: output voltage can be regulated between 0V and 1V, R3 also functions as GPIO protection (in case potentiometer is screwed to the end).  If you like it you can use the picture in your answer.  I shall delete my answer after you confirm.

Comment: Yes that is the idea but use smaller values of resistance to make the potential divider and I wouldn’t use a potentiometer.

Answer (score 1):

I think your circuit could work, but only in a few selected cases.

You have to take into account, that your Fets have a \$R_{{ds}_{on}}\$, which will influence the output voltage if significant current is drawn by the load.
Hence you will encounter a voltage below 3.3 V depending on the load.

I recommend using a voltage reference with a reference input like the TLV431.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmUR4J.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This allows a rather precise voltage output, which is much more stable. Capacitors are omitted, please look up the application notes in the datasheet. Also, as soon as you have knowledge about the impedance of your load, adapt R3 to your needs.

If you have the money, there are references with an additional enable pin, which could save you some of the external discretes.